# Next.js Stop Propagation on a nested Link element

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have these tiles that are clickable which while send the user to some external page plus a button inside of the tile that should route the user to some page inside of the site. The problem with this is that when clicking on the button, both events are fired so it sends the user to the external page + navigates to the internal page.

```
<div
  tabIndex={0}
  role="button"
  onClick={onClick}
>
  <div>
    // some markup
    <Link href={url} passHref>
      <a
        role="button"
        onClick={(e) => sendUserToInternalPageEvent(e)}
      >
        // some text
      </a>
    </Link>
  </div>
</div>
```

The event for `sendUserToInternalPageEvent` is using the nextjs event object for the Link component. I'm trying to stop propagation for `sendUserToInternalPageEvent` but `event.stopPropagation()` is undefined. The goal is for `sendUserToInternalPageEvent` to send the user to an internal page while using the nextjs Link element and have `onClick` send the user to the external page.

Comment: question is a bit hard to understand for me, however if you'd like to use event and `stopPropagation` on anchor using Link, you could try to wrap it, e.g. `<div><a ...>...</a></div>`

Comment: @ogostos This didn't give me the desired effect as it stopped the other event I needed.

Answer (score 6):

I ended up going this route

```
const stopPropagation = (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation();
  };
```

```
<div
  tabIndex={0}
  role="button"
  onClick={onClick}
>
  <div>
    // some markup
    <Link href={url} passHref>
      <a
        role="button"
        onClick={(e) => {
          stopPropagation(e);
          if (!disabled) onClick(e);
        }}
      >
        // some text
      </a>
    </Link>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

For Nextjs 13, you can use `e.preventDefault()` before your onClick event

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend swapping out the link element for a div that has an onClick and uses nextjs' router. For example:

```html
<div onClick={() => router.push("/page")}>
  Content
</div>
```

stopPropagation(e); should then work. Keep in mind that this will remove the autoloading that nextjs normally does for links, which you'll need to re-add yourself.

Answer (score 0):

For me worked a combination of

```
onClick={(e) => {
   e.stopPropagation();
   e.nativeEvent.preventDefault();
   // your handler
}}
```